# Can one connect Starlink router with the Mesh via ethernet cable?

Tags: meshing, wifi, wire

I know that with the Starlink ethernet adapter one can connect to the router or mesh with the ethernet cable.

My question is: is it possible to connect Starlink router with the Starlink mesh via ethernet connection?

I have a concrete floor/ceiling between the floors in the house and the signal doesn't get through. But I've got ethernet ports in each room and it is all wired in walls.

So, if, let's say, the router on the first floor doesn't wirelesly see the mesh on the ground floor, if each of these would have an adapter plugged in, and ethernet cable would go into the socket in the wall, would router and mesh "see" each other?

Comment: did you find out?this is what I want to do

Comment: I don't *think* this counts as an engineering question. You might want to ask it on https://superuser.com/ instead (but I'd get a moderator to double-check my opinion since double-posting is also not allowed).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33975)

Comment: You can probably plug a Starlink router into any mesh, and you probably don't need a special mesh system for Starlink. It's probably just an excuse for Elon Musk to charge you extra.